# Elasticsearch passwords tool always returns "setting already set" error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, docker-compose

I am following the official ES documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html#CO2-1) for configuring a basic dev 3 node cluster with TLS using docker compose but am stuck at the 5th step - creating user passwords using the `elasticsearch-setup-passwords` tool.

I have so far been able to get a 3 node cluster working without TLS. I have also torn it down and restarted with certs created and TLS enabled as the docs say and see that the various containers output looks fine. Any attempt to run

```
docker exec es01 /bin/bash -c "bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto --batch -Expack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certificates/es01/es01.crt -Expack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certificates/ca/ca.crt -Expack.security.http.ssl.key=certificates/es01/es01.key --url https://es01:9200"
```

as mentioned in the docs always returns

```
Sets the passwords for reserved users

Non-option arguments:
command

Option             Description
------             -----------
-E <KeyValuePair>  Configure a setting
-h, --help         Show help
-s, --silent       Show minimal output
-v, --verbose      Show verbose output
ERROR: setting [xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities] already set, saw [certificates/ca/ca.crt] and [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/ca/ca.crt]
```

Any one of the settings designated in the command above will throw this "already set" error, yet it is listed in the official documentation. If I run the command as just

```
docker exec es01 /bin/bash -c "bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto --batch --url https://es01:9200"
```

It will generate the passwords as expected.

If I do not specify the xpack security settings will the proper certificated be used? There are some other default certificates that exist in the containers that I do not want to use for this, is there a way I can verify that the correct set was used? Is there a way to overwrite the "already set" settings?

The official documentation does not explain this clearly and I have not been able to find anything for this specifically on SO or the web.

I am using Docker Desktop version 2.2.0.5 for MacOS Catalina version 10.15.4 with Docker Compose version 1.25.4 and ES version 7.7.0

My docker compose file looks like:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic 
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true 
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

    healthcheck:
      test: curl --cacert $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt -s https://localhost:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic
  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${VERSION}
    container_name: kib01
    depends_on: {"es01": {"condition": "service_healthy"}}
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      SERVERNAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: kibana
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: CHANGEME
      ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES: $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      SERVER_SSL_ENABLED: "true"
      SERVER_SSL_KEY: $CERTS_DIR/kib01/kib01.key
      SERVER_SSL_CERTIFICATE: $CERTS_DIR/kib01/kib01.crt
    volumes:
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic
volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
    name: data01
  data02:
    driver: local
    name: data02
  data03:
    driver: local
    name: data03
  certs:
    driver: local
    name: certs

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
    name: elastic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong with your method, just type the below commands in given sequence;

1. docker exec es01 /bin/bash -c "bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords \
   auto --batch \
   --url https://localhost:9200"
2. docker-compose down
3. docker-compose -f elastic-docker-tls.yml up -d

restart your browser and wait until reload.